# How can I change saving file directory?

Tags: java, spring-boot, eclipse-jee

I want to change saving file directory.
Here is it my code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/UploadFile")
public String uploadFile(HttpServletResponse response String base64, String name, String size) throws Exception {
    byte[] decodedFile = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name);
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedFile);
    IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
    response.flushBuffer();
    return "true";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 File path = new File("YOUR PATH HERE") ;
            try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path)) {
                fos.write(decodedFile);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

You should also consider reading these links:

https://medium.com/javarevisited/how-to-upload-files-to-local-directory-in-spring-boot-c8c33f8239d3

https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/

**EDIT**

If String name is original File name, you could also do this:

```
File path = new File("C:\\YOUR_PATH\\images\\" + name);
```

Comment: Thanks but I got a problem ! I can only download the file just one time ! for example if i have a file with  the name `file.csv` I can't download again the `file(1).csv`  ( it can be downloaded only in the downloads not in the specific directory)